# Problems with Views Slideshow: Cycle

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I want to create a slideshow view. I installed and set up the next modules:

Views   7.x-3.7
Views Slideshow 7.x-3.1

I Installed the module

Views Slideshow: Cycle  7.x-3.1

And i downloaded the jquery.cycle.all.min.js and jquery.cycle.all.js, and put into /sites/all/libraries/jquery.cicles/. These two files have the 755 permissions.

But, when I try to set up the module Views Slideshow: Cycle 7.x-3.1, this message appears in my module admin page:

*"You need to install the jQuery cycle plugin. Create a directory in sites/all/libraries called jquery.cycle, and then copy jquery.cycle.all.min.js or jquery.cycle.all.js into it. You can find the plugin at http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle."*

Is anyone who can help me?
thanks

Comment: Hmmm. That should be it. Did you clear Drupal's cache?

Comment: Tanks NickWebman... the solution is the name of the folder, I've an error... that's so embarrassing.

Comment: haha well I missed it too :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the name of the folder.

You have this: /sites/all/libraries/jquery.cicles/

And the correct is /sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle/ (note the last "s"  is removed, and is "cycle" not "cicle").

Try it and I think it will work.

Regards.

Comment: Upss... that's so embarrassing. Thanks Mario!